# Having different configurations on Pantheios

Tags: c++, logging, pantheios

This question is regarding logging in C++ with Pantheios library.
   In my application, I need to have these different loggers:

- One that logs the critical messages to logFile1 and to Console
- One that logs the warning messages to logFile2
- One that logs the error messages to WindowsEventLog

  I'm wondering if I can do it in panthios.

  I guess my question is: How can I have different settings (like severity levels, different filenames) for different log entries.

  Also, do we have any logging hierarchies here in Pantheios that I can use for my different subsystems?

  Can I change these configurations at runtime?

Thanks,
Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may be after is Extended Severity Information. These two links might help:
* http://blog.pantheios.org/2009/05/use-of-extended-severity-information.html
* severity_information_2example_8cpp_8misc_8extended__sea251715135bb302f75cbc1fd50584869.html">http://www.pantheios.org/doc/html/cpp_2misc_2example_8cpp_8misc_8extended_*severity*_information_2example_8cpp_8misc_8extended__sea251715135bb302f75cbc1fd50584869.html